# Changes in Model class causes drop database first and recreate, How to avoid this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In Models context file it was mentioned

> If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
>   automatically whenever you change your model schema, add the following
>   code to the Application_Start method in your Global.asax file. Note:
>   this will destroy and re-create your database with every model change.

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<HMS.Models.HMSContext>());
```

so I added this code in the `Global.asax` file inside `protected void Application_Start()`.

Adding this line drops whole database when I do any changes in model class. Is there any alternate way to avoid this and still I can do Model changes?

i.e After performing changes in model when I rebuild and run my application, it drops my database and regenerate all the empty model tables. So I loose all my entered data and I want to preserve table data.

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi I have added two new lines at end of question for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EF Code First 4.1, then, no, it will only drop and recreate. EF version 5 apparently supports dynamically changing the underlying database. It's in beta at the moment, but is available for production use if you want to try it out. You can install it through NuGet.

Comment: Suppose, If i am working on database that is having 3 to 4 foreign keys then I have to add all those data again if I do changes in model???

Comment: It can be helpful in many ways to have SQL scripts that allow you to drop your database at any time (on purpose, by accident or through disaster) and recreate a new database, including required default data for tables containing lookup values.  Other developers can then use these and you can use for any set-up tear-down routines in testing.

Comment: You can automatically update indices and foreign keys by overriding DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<[your db context class]> and then context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("...")

Comment: As another option, just turn off drop and recreate using
Database.SetInitializer<[your db context class>(null);
and manually create new columns as you change your model.

Comment: Hello @Steve Owen , it means that I need to remove that `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<[your db context class]>` line and perform changes at both side i.e in database table and in Model code. Will it work fine then?

Comment: Yes, if you manually update the database to match the model it will work. You might find it easier to have a separate test database that you do allow EF to update (using a different context name), and then you can copy the columns it creates, so you know you get them right. Or I've just noticed that EF4.3 also supports dynamic growing of the underlying db structure, but it's not something I've tried yet (although I'm about to!)